# User can not access network printers with Windows 7 connected to Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows, shared-printers

A single user on Windows 7 on a Windows Domain can not access/use/manipulate network printers shared from a server running Windows 2008 R2.  The error that occurs is "0x00000005 Access is denied".  Any other user I create in the system can access and print to said printers, even with identical group memberships.  I expect that if I wipe out the user's local profile (it's not a roaming profile), it will remove the problem.

**Is there anything specific that can be checked in the user's profile or Registry HKCU to discover the cause of the "access is denied" error?**

Details:

- All printers shared from the Windows Server are failing with "0x00000005 Access is denied" when the user attempts to view the printer properties, view the print queue, or print to the printer.
- The problem *is* specific to the local user profile.  This user on other computers does not fail and other users on this computer also do not fail.
- Killing the local user profile and starting it from scratch is completely off the table.
- Testing the Effective Permissions for this user shows that the user does have the "Print" and "Read Permissions" privileges on the affected printers.

Edit: This user's computer ended up with a virus afterward and so we wiped and reinstalled the system.  The problem didn't occur after the wipe.

Comment: silly question, but you mention "local user" - are they not a domain user?

Comment: They are a domain user.  I was referring to their profile being local on the computer, not roaming or otherwise.

Comment: Interesting issue. Since it's solved by reinstalling the OS to remove the virus (which caused the issue), I recommend you create an answer to this question with the info in "Edit" you provided above. It will help others to solve their similar problem, and prevent those looking for open questions from stumbling on this. Congrats on solving it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This user's computer ended up with a virus afterward and so we wiped and reinstalled the system. The problem didn't occur after the wipe.  I would consider this a non-answer.